# microsft security essentials last update definition time is messed up

Tags: ms-security-essentials

It's been a while since my laptop lost track of time. I've been living with it so far, and I've developed a simple script to update computer time using an script every minute. But the problem is MSE somehow managed to update it's definition when my time was wrong. Right now it says definition was updated at 1/18/2018. So it keeps telling me my latest definition update (created on 12/23/2012) is too old. How can I fix this problem? Here is an screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out nothing could actually fix that problem, except waiting for a new definition update. I literally didn't do anything, but updating MSE a few days later. The problem was solved, but last night jump to the future (again) and exact same issue appeared.

Comment: I would uninstall then reinstall and see if the problem continues.

Answer (score 2):

> It's been a while since my laptop lost track of time. I've been living with it so far

Check your laptop’s manual to find out how to change the battery. In the meantime, just get a time-sync program and set it up to sync every hour or two (or just make sure that Windows’ own time-sync service is enabled and configured).

> I've developed a simple script to update computer time using an script every minute.

Why? Is it really going out of sync *that fast*‽

> MSE somehow managed to update it's definition when my time was wrong. Right now it says definition was updated at 1/18/2018. So it keeps telling me my latest definition update (created on 12/23/2012) is too old. How can I fix this problem?

Check Windows Update to see if you can apply the latest MSSE definitions through that instead of through MSSE. Then you should see the correct time in MSSE.

Alternately, you should be able to [manually download and install](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971606) the latest defs which should reset the time.

Comment: I've tried changing the battery but it didn't fix the problem here is the [full story](http://superuser.com/questions/517034/computer-clock-not-working-properly). besides in less than 24 hours my computer is get about 5-6 hours off. and the real problem is sometimes the clock jumps to another time, that's why there is an script updating time that fast! and updating MSE didn't solve the problem, as I explained it keep bugging me since he thinks there should be a newer update (due to the wrong date). Though I'm going to try manual updating hopefully it'll fix it.